# Single-Member LLC vs LLC having only one member

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company

So, I registered a LLC but I am the only member in this LLC. If I do business under this LLC, when I file tax, I think I should NOT choose "Individual/sole proprietor or single-member LLC" category, right?

Instead, I think I should choose "Limited liability company - Disregarded Entity". Does this make sense? Is this the correct category?

Thanks a million!

Comment: What a weird set of categories.  Did the IRS issue this, or is this some stupid third party tax software/service? .  A single member LLC is *the same thing* as an LLC with one member.  Presuming the LLC does not elect S-corp tax treatment -- a sole proprietor, SMLLC and ”disregarded entity” are again *the same thing* as far as tax treatment!

Comment: @Harper Thank you for the response. I think single-member LLC in the first case is the individual doing business without registering the LLC but will be treated as a LLC with single member in terms of filing tax. Not sure If that's the reason...

Comment: Nah, if he hasn't registered the LLC then he's a *sole proprietor*.  Is this an IRS document? Can you link it?

Comment: If you haven't registered, it's not an LLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that:

- "Individual/sole proprietor or single-member LLC" -- Applies to a single-member LLC with pass-through taxation (i.e., you haven't elected to be taxed as a corporation)
- "Limited liability company - Disregarded Entity" -- Applies to a multi-member LLC that is taxed as a partnership (this is also pass-through taxation but is more complicated since the partnership needs to file its own tax return)

You should choose the first one.